# Multiple regex matching in filebeat for message field

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, filebeat

I want to apply 2 regex expression with filebeat to drop events matching the content in message field.

I am able to make it work for single regex condition, but I am not sure how to configure multiple regex conditions.

regex list:

- `message: "(?i)cron"`
- `message: "^now ([0-9]{4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])\s([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$"`

Following is the config I have done for single regex which will match "cron" case insensitive text anywhere in the message

```
- drop_event:
     when:
         regexp:
             message: "(?i)cron"
```

Refering to the Filebeat docs, I tried multiple configs but  then filebeat won't startup:

- Try 1:

```
- drop_event:
    or:
     - regexp:
        message: "(?i)cron"
     - regexp:
        message: "^now ([0-9]{4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])\s([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$"
```

- Try 2:

```
- if:
    regexp:
      message: "(?i)cron"
  then:
    drop_event:
- if:
    regexp:
      message: "^now ([0-9]{4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])\s([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$"
  then:
    drop_event:
```

Comment: This may help you [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/regexp-support.html#composites) using multiple regex patterns. Although filebeat recommends wrap regular expressions in single quotation marks to work around YAML’s string escaping rules. ex: `pattern1here|pattern2here`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured Out How we can apply multiple filter using or operator in filebeat. I was close in the second attempt in the post. When is required, after that we can use whatever operator we like `or` `and` etc.

Here's example of how I am using it

```yaml
processors:
  - drop_event.when:
     or:
     - contains:
         container.name: "nginx"
     - contains:
         container.name: "mongo"
     - contains:
         container.name: "mysql"
     - contains:
         container.name: "redis"
     - equals:
         container.name: "tecnativa/tcp-proxy"

  - drop_event.when:
     or:
     - regexp:
         message: "(?i)cron"
     - regexp:
         message: "In On Child added message"
     - regexp: 
         message: "In on Child removed message"
     - regexp:
         message: "then Moment"
     - regexp: 
         message: "call_duration"
     - regexp: 
         message: "now Moment"
     - regexp: 
         message: "CHAT NOTIFICATION CODE"
```